# Numpy indexing in $n$ dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `n`-dimensional array `arr` in which I need to modify `k` entries, which are specified in an separate array `pos` with shape `(k, n)`. If the dimension `n` is fixed, this can be easily achieved using `arr[pos[:, 0], pos[:, 1]] = 1`. How could this be generalized to `n` dimensions?

A working example for the specific case `n=3` is

```
k = 6
a = np.zeros((4, 4, 4))
pos = np.random.randint(0, 4, size=(k, a.ndim))
a[pos[:, 0], pos[:, 1], pos[:, 2]] = 1
```

Comment: Do `a[tuple(pos.T)] = 1`.

Comment: Great! If you formulate it as an answer, Ill accept it